# Handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException : Ajax File Uploading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

How can I effectively handle `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` in an `ajax` based file uploading operation.

I have an ajax based file upload functionality. I need to handle the `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` when user upload a file whose size exceeds the maximum allowed. I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception/3230352), where user will be directed to a error page, when file size exceeds. Since I am using ajax request to upload file, I want to show a `javascript` alert in the browser when file size exceeds, instead of redirecting to some error page.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to completely follow the solution in your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception/3230352), where, on exception you would redirect to an *error.jsp*, which would in fact return JSON, so as simple as

**error.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
{"errors":"${errors}"}
```

in which case the *success* part of your ajax call would be

```
success : function(json) {
   alert(json.errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in Ajax, since you asked to show using javascript ,You can use **ActiveXObject** if you are using browsers that doesn't support HTML 5. If you are using modern browsers, you can use File APIs like below,

```
$('#fileId').bind('change', function() {
  //The below code will get the size of the uploaded file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

You will get the file size in bytes, you can divide the file size by 1024 for getting in kb.