# FileSizeLimitExceededException can not be handled in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, exception

When I try to upload a file, I get `FileSizeLimitExceededException` exception and I can't handle it in my controller class.

My exception handler looks like the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleFileSizeLimitExceeded(Exception exc) {
        
        System.out.println("In Exception handler");
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.addObject("imageUploadMessage", "File too big");
         modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", user);
 
        modelAndView.setViewName("profile");

        return          modelAndView;
    }
```

I have seen several similar questions on `Stackoverflow` about this problem, but many of them don't have an accepted answer and the proposed answers there also could not solve my problem.
For example, I tried `FileSizeLimitExceededException`, `MultipartException` and `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` in my exception handler, but the controller is never triggered at all.
Following the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception), I tried the following settings in my `propertis` file:

```
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=true
```

But also no success.

Is there any solution to this problem?

In the meantime, I want to return a `ModelAndView` as the return statement.

I hope somebody has found a real solution to this problem so far :).

Update 1:
Here is the screenshot of the exception:
[image]

Comment: What file size did you test? If it > 100MB I suspect Tomcat will break the connection and you won't see the response with ModelAndView.

Comment: Moreover, it would be good if you provide logs and actual response

Comment: @AndreiKovrov The file I try to upload is a picture of size 16 MB. I upodated my question with a screenshot of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I just needed to update the verison of the `Spring` in my `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Define another class for global MaxUploadSizeExceededException handling. Below code is triggered only MaxUploadSizeExceededException exception thrown.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleFileSizeLimitExceeded(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("In Exception handler");
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.addObject("imageUploadMessage", "File too big");
        modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", user);

        modelAndView.setViewName("profile");

        return          modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code doesn't work. I changed it to somehow and it seems better. But the only difference is that I don't get any error in the output of my eclipse. But it does NOT return to the current page and does not show the message I have set in the modelAndView.

Comment: hi, I have tested the code with ResponseEntity response. I saw the breakpoint is visited into the function. Did you try to put any breakpoints in the function?

Comment: I also got the function triggered when implemented using ControllerAdvice and if I set a breakpoint there, I also see that. You're right. But it seems that returning "ModelAndView" is not working properly there. I can't get redirected to the page I was there before. When I implement it this way, I don't get any exception in my eclipse and I don't return to the previous page, but I just see a "connection interrupted" page.

Comment: If you can return the code to the current page, could you please share your code with me.