# How to return Custom Response for MaxUploadSizeExceededException during MultiPart File Upload Request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, error-handling, multipart

I'm using a Spring Boot 2.7.5 Backend for a Multipart File Upload.
I want to return a Custom Response if the uploaded file exceeds the specified upload size limit in the configuration.

I originally tried using an ExceptionHandler in a ControllerAdvice as such:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = [MaxUploadSizeExceededException::class])
    fun handleSizeLimitExceededException(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val fileSizeMegabyte = multipartProperties.maxFileSize.toMegabytes().toString()
        val message = "The file is too big for the upload. Files are not allowed to be bigger than $fileSizeMegabyte MB"
        LOG.warn(message)
        return ResponseEntity(CustomErrorDto(FILE_TOO_LARGE, message, mapOf("maxFileSize" to fileSizeMegabyte)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
```

Now this code gets executed, but it is ultimately ignored, as the Multipart Exception already gets handled (Connection Aborted) before the ControllerAdvice is even in play.

`An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE8021E: The file being uploaded is too large.`

I tried using the `spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily: true` property which seemed to work for some people in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception), as well as using an ErrorController (which is not applicable for my use case, as it is not a Spring MVC application)

Any hints will be much appreciated, so if you ever dealt with this or a similar issue, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!